# Time Tracking - Best method?

Tags: php, javascript, time-tracking, sockets

I'm looking to track the time it takes users to traverse through a few forms I have on a website.

My old thought was to use something like jQuery to poll the server updating the time spent on a page, but it appears this would be incredibly resource intensive.

Recently I've been reading about sockets.io and node.js. It seems like the connection and disconnection methods might be a perfect way to track time.

Before I dive into learning all about sockets etc, is there a better way for doing this? I know I could do this server side, but it'll fall over if someone abandon's the site entirely midway through the process, and with sockets I could even track down to the length of time spent on each form field if I wanted.

Comment: Is thier a business requirement behind this or is it expiremental/debugging/curiosity driven?  Also what if they just walk away from their computer to get some coffee?  Will this affect your use case?

Comment: It's more to see where the forms could be improved as time goes on - the end user's will normally fill in from start to finish in one go due to the nature of the forms use (It's a one off system that they'll rarely use twice). The target audience will be of all different skill levels in using computers, so it'd be helpful for improvement on question labels, form flow etc.

Comment: Store the time, when the form is requested. Store again, when form is submitted. Seems to me as simple as this. Otherwise as maple_shaft already pointed out, you won't get very good data anyway. (And polling the server once in a while shouldn't kill it or you have a serious bottleneck problem anyway)

Comment: if you want advice on how to layout your forms for ease of use you should go to ux.stackExchange

Comment: @ratchetfreak - I don't want advice on laying them out, just a way to track use for now

Comment: @thorstenmüller But server side only wont allow me to track individual questions, and general polling just screams of unnecessary traffic being created to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Decent web analytic package will go this for you. If that doesn't work for you I would analyze the web logs.

I don't think this is something you want code into your front end.

Comment: Do you know of any packages that could track progress through a form? I haven't seen anything like that in GA at least, would love it if you knew of any?

Comment: https://www.google.com/analytics will do that. As will many others.

Comment: I've just found some more info on this in GA - looks pretty much perfect and will save me hours! Google should really make this a bit more obvious within the app :/ Thanks.

Comment: I use Statcounter for my sites where I'm not using another Google product (Adsense, Adwords). No need to give the Big G more data they can use for their own nefarious purposes.